# Sort Arrays.toString()

Tags: java, arrays

I'd like to create an array of size 10 filled with random numbers and sort them. Pretty basic. Here's what I wrote:

```
static String OrdenarVector(){
    int[] vectoraleatorio = new int[10];        
    Random r = new Random();

    for(int a = 0; a < 10; a++){
        int numeroaleatorio = r.nextInt();
        vectoraleatorio[a] = numeroaleatorio;
    }

    return Arrays.toString(vectoraleatorio);
}
```

It works fine but I'd like to sort that vector. I tried to create a new vector `novovetor` and use `Arrays.sort(vectoraleatorio)` but it didn't work for me. I also tried to combine `Arrays.sort` with `Arrays.toString()` but I'm getting errors with no suggestions available. Sorry if its a duplicate.

Hugs

Comment: Post the error message you get.

Comment: You should stick to the Java Naming Conventions: method names always start with lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with the `Arrays.sort` before return:

```
Arrays.sort(vectoraleatorio);
return Arrays.toString(vectoraleatorio);
```

Answer (score 0):

Be careful, the sort method doesn't return anything. This should work:

```
  public static String OrdenarVector(){

    int[] vectoraleatorio = new int[10];        
    Random r = new Random();

    for(int a = 0; a < 10; a++){
        int numeroaleatorio = r.nextInt();
        vectoraleatorio[a] = numeroaleatorio;
    }

    Arrays.sort(vectoraleatorio);
    return Arrays.toString(vectoraleatorio);

   }
```